# How do I get the correct value from onNext in RxSwift?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, rx-swift, swifty-json

I have `parsed` `JSON` data from an `URL` and the `subscriber` on the `array` trigger accordingly as the `array` is populated. But the data that I get from `onNext` look like this: `MyProject.People`. How do I get the actual values? Here's my code:

```
guard let myURL = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/e5gjk") else { return }
var myArray: Variable<[People]> = Variable([])

myArray.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { arrayData in
    print("TRIGGERED", arrayData)

    }).disposed(by: bag)

Alamofire.request(myURL, method: .get)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON{ response in

    guard response.result.isSuccess else {
       print("Error")
       return
    }

    let json = JSON(response.result.value)

    for i in 0...json["employees"].count {
        let people = People()
        people.name = json["employees"][i]["firstName"].stringValue
         people.job = json["employees"][i]["job"].stringValue

         myArray.value.append(people)
    }

    for i in myArray.value {
        print(i.name)
        print(i.job)
    }
}
```

So, `arrayData` returns `MyProject.People` but should give strings. I have tried `arrayData.name` and `arrayData.value.name` but it doesn't show anything. `People` look like this:

```
class People {
    var name = ""
    var job = ""
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug? to see your `json` result? And i believe this line will crash, because index will out of range `for i in 0...json["employees"].count`

Comment: If I put a print after the for loop where the array has been populated, I can see all the data in `myArray` so that part works. Don't get a crash either. But I think you are right as the loops are run one more time than there is actually data, so I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would **suggested** you to use `Codable` protocol instead of `JSON` pod.
You can read more about `Codable` here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/codable/

And more about `CustomStringConvertible` here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible

This can be as simple as this:

```
class Employees: Codable {
    let employees: [Employee]
}

/// If you want to print array with values
/// A textual representation of this instance.
extension Employees: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var text = ""
        for employee in employees {
            text += "Employee first name: \(employee.firstName), Job: \(employee.job)\n"
        }
        return text
    }
}

class Employee: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let job: String
}
```

---

I also try simple `request` and it's finish successfully, i was able to get all entities: (you can change *Alamofire* response from `responseJSON` to `responseData`)

```
let employees = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Employees.self, from: response.data)
print(employees)
...
```

```
Employee first name: Jocke, Job: developer
Employee first name: Anna, Job: construction
Employee first name: Peter, Job: pilot
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you think you could print the code as a whole? :)

Comment: As I stated in my answer, just change `.responseJSON` to `.responseData` and paste my code where you decode `response data` to your object than conforms to `Codable`

Comment: I get the decoding part to work. I get the values as expected. And the `rx` subscriber is triggered. But I still get the same print: `MyProject.People`. Did you get the correct values there?

Comment: @screenMonkeyMonkeyMan I got it and edit my answer. Added `CustomStringConvertible` with `description` property where you can add your own textual representation of instance.

Comment: Ah, ok, `CustomStringConvertible` did it for me. It worked for both `JSON` and `JSONDecoder` so the conversion was what was missing. Thanks for enlightening me! :)

Answer (score 1):

myArray.value is an array of [People], it's not allowed direct access people property (name, job). You have to get people from particular index, then you can access people’s property.